# SQL - Order records by the closest value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have created one API for product details
In this API I also need to attach similar products in response.

So for similar products scenario are like following
1) Price wise (+10 and -10)
2) Then after category wise (From same category)

e.g.
I have product with id #30 and price with $30 and category with "beer"
SO the similar products listing will be like following
First show all products beer category products which are come between range +10 and -10 of $30 (I mean b/w range 20 to 40)
Then after attach other products which are belongs from same category "beer" with closest price of $30
Suppose products price with same category are following
$10, $17, $45, $42, $50

so the products will sort as following as closet to $30
$42 ($42 - $30 = 12), $17 ($30 - $17 = 13), $45 ($45 - $30 = $15), $10 ($30 - $10 = $20), $50 ($50 - $30 = $20)

for similar products in +10 -10 range i created below query

```
similar_price = Product.includes(:sub_category, :brand, :product_type, :category).in_stock.where("(actual_price BETWEEN ? AND ? AND category_id = ? ) ", min_price, max_price, self.category_id)
```

now i need to order products with closest price.
How can fix this issue with postgres query in rails ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can perform this operation by using just simple order query as like following

```
`Product.where("product.category_id = ?", "category_id").order("abs(products.price - #{your_selected_product_price})")`
```

Comment: let me try first

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is dangerous to use if the price comes from untrusted user input, since it allows SQL injection. It also breaks if price can be `nil`.

The solution is to properly quote the price for the given column:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :closest_by_price, ->(price) {
    quoted_price = connection.quote(price, columns_hash["price"])
    order("abs(products.price - #{quoted_price})")
  }
end

Product.closest_by_price(50.0)
```