# Order records by closest specific price number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to give recommendations on product show page with similar products' price.

So considering:

```
@products = Product.all
@specific_product = Product.all.find(20)
@price = @specific_product.price
```

How can I get the 10th products records with the most closest price to this one ?

Something like:

```
@products = Products.all.order_closest_by(price: @price).limit(10)
```

Comment: Most naive way would be to normalize the price of the products (e.g by calculating the absolute difference between the specific product and the all products in @products). Then sort the results in ascending order and take the first 10.

Comment: Hi @NayeemZen, I guess that I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48563576/sql-order-records-by-the-closest-value

Comment: @jvillian yes it is almost the same

Answer (score 0):

[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48563576/sql-order-records-by-the-closest-value) answered the question.

So I have to do:

```
@products = Products.all.order("abs(price - #{@price})")
```

Comment: Yes this works, but make sure that `@price` does not come from users (eg. the `params` hash) or you open up yourself to SQL injections. This code will also break if price can be nil. I'll post another answer that shows how to do this safely.

Comment: Since this question is marked as a duplicate, I posted my answer on the post you referred to above.